# Prove that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ constructed by Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Does my attempt look fine or contain logical flaws/gaps? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

Let $\mathcal{C}$  be the set of Cauchy sequences of rationals. We define an equivalence relation $\sim$  on $\mathcal{C}$  by $$(a_n) \sim (b_n) \iff \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N, \forall n>N: |a_n - b_n| < \epsilon$$

Let $\mathcal{C} / {\sim}$  be the set of all equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals. We define a relation $\preccurlyeq$  on $\mathcal{C} / {\sim}$  by $$[(a_n)] \preccurlyeq [(b_n)] \iff \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N, \forall n>N: a_n - b_n < \epsilon$$

I have shown that $\preccurlyeq$  is a complete linear ordering [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105881/prove-that-the-system-of-real-numbers-is-complete-by-cauchy-sequence).

I have shown that $[(a_n)] \prec [(b_n)] \iff \exists \epsilon >0, \exists N, \forall n>N: \epsilon \le b_n -a_n$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107045/prove-that-three-following-statements-regarding-the-complete-linear-ordering-of).

> **Theorem:** $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

---

**My attempt:**

$[(a_n)] \prec [(b_n)] \implies \exists \epsilon' >0, \exists N', \forall n>N': \epsilon \le b_n -a_n$.

$(a_n),(b_n)$ are Cauchy sequences $\implies$ $\exists N'', \forall m,n > N'': |a_m - a_n| < \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \wedge |b_m - b_n| < \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4}$.

Let $N_0 = \max \{N'+1,N''+1\}$. It follows that $\epsilon \le b_{N_0} -a_{N_0}$ and $\forall n > N_0: |a_n - a_{N_0}| < \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \wedge |b_n - b_{N_0}| < \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4}$.

Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence whose all elements are equal to $\dfrac{a_{N_0} + b_{N_0}}{2}$. It follows directly that $[(x_n)]$ is rational.

Next we prove $[(a_n)] \prec [(x_n)] \prec [(b_n)]$.

$n > N_0 \implies  |a_n - a_{N_0}| < \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \implies a_n < a_{N_0} + \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \implies$ $\dfrac{a_{N_0} + b_{N_0}}{2} - a_n > \dfrac{b_{N_0}-a_{N_0}}{2}-\dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \ge \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}-\dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} = \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \implies$ $\exists \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} >0, \exists N_0, \forall n>N_0: \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \le \dfrac{a_{N_0} + b_{N_0}}{2} -a_n \implies [(a_n)] \prec [(x_n)]$.

$n > N_0 \implies  |b_n - b_{N_0}| < \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \implies b_{N_0} - \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} < b_n \implies$ $b_n - \dfrac{a_{N_0} + b_{N_0}}{2} > \dfrac{b_{N_0}-a_{N_0}}{2}-\dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \ge \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}-\dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} = \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \implies$ $\exists \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} >0, \exists N_0, \forall n>N_0: \dfrac{\epsilon'}{4} \le b_n - \dfrac{a_{N_0} + b_{N_0}}{2} \implies [(x_n)] \prec [(b_n)]$.

Comment: You are using "dense" in the order theoretic sense. Using it in the real analysis sense (any real has a sequence of rationals converging to that real) is much more natural to the Cauchy construction of the reals, and therefore much easier. Is there a specific reason you didn't do it that way, or did you just not consider it?

Comment: Maybe you should make it explicit that you identify $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with the (class of the) constant sequence with value $q$ (which is indeed Cauchy), so that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ makes sense.

Comment: @Arthur For that he has to define a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (the set of classes) first and he cannot define a metric (circular, as a metric already needs the reals) so you have to use the order anyway.

Comment: nitpick: the $\varepsilon$ must be chosen rational or even of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n>0$ a natural number.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Arthur I am self-studing from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech. This approach is suggested by the authors. IMHO, I found your definition of dense (**any real has a sequence of rationals converging to that real**) trivially obvious from the construction of $\Bbb R$ from Cauchy sequences ($\Bbb R$ is the set of all equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma 1. Your interpretation of *Dense* is what I would like to communicate. 2. Yeah I should have made clear that *identify $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with the (class of the) constant sequence with value $q$*. 3. I thought that we all implicit understand that $\epsilon \in \Bbb Q$ and $N \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification! @JoséCarlosSantos!

Comment: In Hrbacek and Jech dense means order dense. Look it up in the index. It's defined twice (in my 2nd edition). So your proof indeed works.